# Single Class compilation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to compile single class  in idea-intellij

After creating a project,I have created multiple classes but whenever I run a single class the whole project gets compiled,I just want to compile a single class
In that picture I just want to compile and run the loop.java class but whenever I do so the customized the java opens up automatically even if I cut it
 [image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX8jr.png)

Comment: One of the *advantages* of an IDE is that it always compiles your source files in the background, so you immediately know if there are compilation errors, and so you don't have to wait when you want to *run* the code. Why is it a problem that all of them are kept compiled, even if you only run one of them? --- Anyway, if you want your source files to be independently managed, put them in different projects.

Comment: Side note: If you setup a project using Gradle, it would do incremental compilation, and only compile *changed files*...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for,but Intellij has a Terminal window,you can `cd` on your `src` files and type `javac ClassIwantToCompile.java`. javac stands for Java Compile.If that brings an error make sure you have your `PATH` variables set correctly.If you want to compile your whole program,you can `cd` in the folder where your classes are located and type `javac *.java` .That essentially means "compile ALL the .java files".

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the class file tab in Intellij and you will get a menu, you can then choose

**Recompile className** (ServerMgr.java in the example shown)

[image: ExampleMenu]

Alternatively you can Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> (Windows default)

Comment: I am to trying to run that loop  class in the picture  but the whole project starts running when I Run it